# How to render @IBDesignable UITableViewCell in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, xib

I create a UITableViewCell subclass CustomTableViewCell and mark it as @IBDesignable. In CustomTableViewCell.xib file I drag a label to its center, then setup an @IBOutlet and name this label as contentLabel. Next, I drag a TableViewCell and put it on a ViewController's table view in the storyboard file, and change its class to CustomTableViewCell. My question is: how to render this contentLabel in the storyboard?

The following snippet doesn't work and I believe it's because contentLabel is not initialized yet in init(), but I want to give it an initial text and render it in the storyboard. How to achieve this?

```
@IBDesignable class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var contentLabel: UILabel!
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        contentLabel.text = "Hello"
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        contentLabel.text = "Hello"
    }
}
```

EDIT: This cell needs to reused in several different view controllers.

Comment: Why you are creating @IBDesignable Cell? You can create Custom UITableViewCell class and assign this class to UITableView's prototype cell Directly in Storyboard. Also you can set initial text directly in storyboard.

Comment: @AshwaniKumar Because this UITableViewCell needs to be reused in several view controllers